# How to pass two array to a ForEach activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have two Lookup activity in my pipeline and I want to pass arrays of both Lookup activity in one ForEach activity.
Here is the sample scenario:-
[image]

Comment: did it answer your query ?

Comment: ya, it ansewered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Array functions to create a common array like union
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/working-with-arrays-in-azure-data-factory

and use it in For each